# YouTube autorepeat a video?

Tags: youtube

I want to display a YouTube video repeatedly at breakfast/dinner time in my kitchen.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can right click a video on YouTube and select 'Loop'. This will play the video continuously.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add the video to a new playlist (and do not add anything else). Start playing from the playlist and enable the auto playback feature. Youtube will then keep looping the same playlist (which also means that the same video will keep playing repeatedly).

Answer (score 2):

Say you're at `youtube.com/watchv?=123456`, simply put the word replay in front of the YouTube in the first link.

In other words:

1. `youtube.com/watchv?=123456`
2. `*replay*youtube.com/watchv?=123456`

This will redirect you to a site dedicated to replaying YouTube videos. Nice & quick.

Answer (score 1):

I personally didn't want to create a new playlist for just a single track so I found another way to do this from the Chrome browser console. But this'll work only if you are viewing the video or track with the HTML5 video player on youtube.

```
var ytvid = $('video');  // Youtube uses jQuery, so ...
var ytloop = window.setInterval(function(){if(ytvid.ended){ytvid.play()}}, 1000);
```

And if you want to stop the loop

```
window.clearInterval(ytloop);
```

**This only works for HTML5 videos**

Comment: Please note that "above" doesn't really have any context here. Answers can be sorted in a number of different ways. Better to make use a link to the answer.

Comment: Excuse me if I don't immediately get your point. Are you suggesting that I remove this post. If so, I will.

Comment: No, I think your post is fine. But "I find the above solution useful" doesn't mean anything unless it's guaranteed your post is below the one you reference. If someone re-sorts the answers or another answer is added, no one will know what post you're referring to.

Comment: Your "edit" should probably be a separate answer.

Comment: lol.. I tried, but stackexchange suggests I do an edit

Comment: It's just a suggestion; you can create a second answer. In the meantime, I've created an answer (and made it Community Wiki).

Answer (score 1):

I made a bookmarklet for doing this; you can find it here: [YouTube Video Looping Bookmarklet](http://amacfie.github.io/RepeatYouTubeVideos/).